# C++ understanding multithreading with global variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a C++ program which declares some global variables. After that it splits up into several threads to do several tasks.
Those threads read and write some of these global variables.

Will there be an app-crash if two threads are ***reading*** the same variable? Or will there be an app-crash only if one thread ***writes*** to a variable which another thread is currently reading?

So if the answer to my second question would be yes, would the following code sample solve this problem?

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

mutex m;
string var = "foo";

// function to provide read and write access
// "protected" with mutex
string test(string value = "")
{
    m.lock();
    if (value == "")
    {
        m.unlock();
        return var;
    }
    else
    {
        var = value;
        m.unlock();
        return "";
    }
}

void thread1()
{
    // use global variable local
    string localVar = test();
}
void thread2()
{
    // overwrite global variable
    test("bar");
}
void thread3()
{
    // use global variable local
    string localVar = test();
}

int main()
{    
    thread t1(thread1);
    thread t2(thread2);
    thread t3(thread3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

furthermore: is this part

```
// ...
if (value == "")
{
    m.unlock();
    return var;
}
// ...
```

also thread-save?

And my last question: my program currently uses only one mutex to prevent that two threads (the same function!) are running simultaneously. I am not using mutexes for my global variables. Could it be that this "situation" can cause an app-crash (module: "ntdll.dll") with the exception code 0xc0000005 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: btw, used _scoped locks_ please!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mutiple reads are always thread safe.  As soon as one thread is writing to a non-atomic variable `var` whilst other threads are reading from `var` you're in danger of a race condition.  So you're almost there, but use mutex guards (they're RAII and therefore exception safe and cleaner C++), something like:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
// ...
std::mutex m;
std::string var = "foo";
// ...
std::string test(const std::string& value = "")
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (value == "")
    {
        return var;
    }
    else
    {
        var = value;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! But what makes `lock_guard(m)` "better" than `m.lock()`? What is the difference?

Comment: Nothing you just don't need to write unlock.

Comment: @SaschaP - if an exception is thrown, the mutex will be unlocked

Comment: but how does `lock_guard(m)` know which variable to protect?

Comment: @SaschaP you are co-coordinating that by only reading and writing to the `var` variable while `m` is `locked`.  That's how `mutex` works :)

Comment: @PaulEvans I'm overburdened with that much answers :-P

Comment: @SaschaP - let me help you here... Paul has the best solution. It's clean and safe. My answer explains what's going on and why/when you should lock things. Accept Paul's answer, and upvote both :-)

Comment: @SaschaP Amit has a better explanation so you should accept his answer :-)))

Comment: @Amit and PaulEvans: thank you both! I chose Paul's solution but if I could I also would have chosen Amit's solution ;-)

Comment: am I right using `lock_guard` like this: `lock_guard<mutex> lock(m);` ?

Comment: @SaschaP yes, that's perfect :-))

Comment: thank you! could you please update it in your answer? :-)

Comment: @SaschaP done, now you can put it in a header file (*never* do `using namespace std;` in them) and you're passing in the `std::string` with a `const` lvalue reference as you should be :-))

Comment: hopefully one last question :-) now I have a global `struct` with private variables and public functions like my above function `test`. Of course each function accesses its own variable, but currently all functions are using the same `mutex m`. Is this possible, or a good/bad practice?

Comment: @SaschaP *always* use one `std::mutex` per variable.  Lock/unlock (with a `std::lock_guard` for each `std::mutex`) each variable with *thier own* `std::mutex`.  And if you need to mutex gaurd more than one at a time, *always* lock in one order (eq A->B->C *etc*) and unlock in the *same* reverse order (eq C->B->A) or you will meet the bad-boy associate of race-condition -- **dead-lock**!!!!

Comment: ok, so my `struct` has 4 variables and 4 methods - one method per variable. And each method uses its own mutex for its variable. Thanks again!

Comment: @SaschaP `std::lock_gaurd` will unlock in the correct order for you if you instantiate them *always* in the same order.  If you have any more questions I suggest opening a new question :)

Comment: @ Yes, even if you only *touch* one variable at a time - give them their own `std::mutex`.  That way you don't lock thread A from altering variable `v1` while thread `B` is altering variable `v2`.

Comment: I'm feeling like I would have enough questions to duplicate StackOverflow's database :-D

Comment: @SaschaP no worries - it's good that you really want to get your head around this :-)))

Answer (score 7):

> Will there be an app-crash if two threads are ***reading*** the same variable?

No. Never. If you're only reading from multiple threads, you're always safe.

> will there be an app-crash only if one thread ***writes*** to a variable which another thread is currently reading?

Not exactly, but it ***can*** lead to a crash, and that's what is happening in your code. It's not "dangerous" in terms of crashing an application to read/write simultaneously from multiple threads. The worst case is that you get garbaged values at some places. That by it's own won't crash your app, but it can definitely lead to that eventually. The problem is when the data you're reading has a meaning other then a primitive value (like an integer for example). For example, if you're reading a memory address (pointer), and then try to access the memory at that address, but the memory is already freed, then you're in trouble - and that's what happens in your code. The characters of the string have moved to a new address, but you're trying to read the old address.

<strike>To solve your problem, you should wrap the entire operation inside the lock, and you could use a temporary variable for this:</strike>

```
string test(string value = "")
{
    m.lock();
    if (value == "")
    {
        string temp = var;
        m.unlock();
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        var = value;
        m.unlock();
        return "";
    }
}
```

The correct solution is in Paul's answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer! +1 for the understandable answer and the solution with the temporary variable ;-)

Comment: Are primitve read/writes atomic ? I could not find much online. Was trying to understand if we need a lock around say, just one global int which gets read in one thread and written to in another thread ? Would there be an intermediate state while writing a primitve ?

Answer (score 2):

> Will there be an app-crash if two threads are **reading** the same
>   variable?

No you can safely read global variable simultaneously (if you know that no one writes to it at the same time). Read operation doesn't modify the global value so it remains the same and all readers "see" the same value.

> Or will there be an app-crash only if one thread **writes** to a
>   variable which another thread is currently reading?

Generally no, at least not because of the simultaneous read vs. write operation. The crash may be a side effect of it. For example if you update a pointer value and read it at the same time then you try to access the data to which the pointer points. If the read value is invalid, most likely you will crash.

> furthermore: is this part
>
> ```
> // ...
> if (value == "")
> {
>     m.unlock();
>     return var;
> }
> // ...
> ```
>
> also thread-save?

No. Your mutex `m` protects only the local variable `value` which has no need to be protected since it is local. But then you release the mutex and copy (**read**) the global `var` variable while another thread may write to it. To make it thread safe, either use `std::lock_guard` and then you won't need manually lock/unlock the mutex. or update the code to this:

```
m.lock();
if (value == "")
{
    string ret_val(var);
    m.unlock();
    return ret_val;
}
```

> I am not using mutexes for my global variables. Could it be that this
>   "situation" can cause an app-crash

As I wrote earlier, yes, as a side effect your app may crash.

Comment: Who was such a jealous and down voted without explaining why?

Comment: @SaschaP I didn't blame you :) Anyone can vote here but I would like to see explanation to the down vote so I could learn from it. Anyway it was up voted back.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question, Simple answer:

Will there be an app-crash if two threads are reading the same variable?

No.

Will there be an app-crash only if one thread writes to a variable which another thread is currently reading?

No.

However you really should use locks and mutexes etc to make sure that you get the expected output for programs. Although the program itself will not crash if one thread writes to a variable being read by another thread, what value do you want the reading thread to actually read? The value before it was written to/over or the value after?

Comment: I'm monitoring a serial port and if new data is available I'm overwriting the global varibale. the second thread is writing this variable (and others) to a file every x seconds. So I would like my reading thread to receive the variable after it was updated...

Comment: Then you best lock those variables!! Use lock_guard<mutex>, that way you don't have to write an unlock manually, when the lock guard goes out of scope at the end of the code block the mutex is released

Comment: If you are working with serial port and threads you probably need something like buffer class with protect access (thread safe) to it. Using pure string as a buffer may result in strange behaviors and may lead to crash.

Comment: @Logman I'm reading the content to a buffer and then write it to a global string :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not thread safe without mutexes

Proposed solution is still not quite right.

var is read outside of the mutex, and could be modified at that time.

This looks like C++11. If `std::string` used shared strings (banned in C++11), that could cause issues with reading.

In the case of reading+writing, then c0000005 (access violation) could occur if a pointer was modified as it was copied.